# Python convert iteration output data into a table and save

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

My function generates a list at the end of each iteration. A sample output is given below:

```
['Apple', 'storage1', 0.670786981803283]
['Apple', 'storage2', 0.21871126661028575]
['Apple', 'storage3', 0.002223827213278317]
['Banana', 'storage1', 0.5838190735354087]
['Banana', 'storage2', 0.012979782583266855]
['Banana', 'storage3', 8.760737814985956e-05]
['Orange', 'storage1', 0.8568037051728143]
['Orange', 'storage2', 0.08342768851519906]
['Orange', 'storage3', 0.000543732080791498]
```

I would like to convert this into a Table consisting of Fruit name on header and storage on left side index and save this table.

My expected output

```
           'Apple'      'Banana'       'Orange' 
Storage1 

Storage2

Storage 3
```

My code:

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(your_lists).pivot()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I tried this. Giving error `
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type

KeyError: None``